# How to pass a HOST header to AWS ALB with gRPC

Tags: grpc, aws-application-load-balancer, grpc-python

I successfully managed to create an ALB that supports gRPC with a private self-signed certificate; however, I was planning on using this ALB to do content-routing of gRPC requests based on the `Host` header that ALB supports. Till now, I tried to no avail. Has anyone had success with this? Here's my code:

```py
import json
import grpc
import base64
from lib import unified_pb2
from lib import unified_pb2_grpc

# Setup
uri = 'internal-test-lb-micky-18886655.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com'
with open('server.crt', 'rb') as f:
    trusted_certs = f.read()
    credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=trusted_certs)
    channel = grpc.secure_channel(f'{uri}:443', credentials)

metadata=( ('host', 'qa.mydomain.com'),)

cf_greeters_stub = unified_pb2_grpc.GreetersStub(channel)
cf_request = unified_pb2.Request()
cf_request.cf_greeters_request.greeter_text = "hello"
data = cf_greeters_stub.GetResponse(cf_request,metadata=metadata)
print(data)
```

My ALB has the rule that intercepts the `Host` header and should route to the right target group based on that, but then ALB is not doing that, passing the request to the default rule. The rule I created returns `200` when there's a match, returns JSON dictionary in the body.

Comment: gRPC uses HTTP2 which honers the ":authority" header in this situation (it's like HOST for HTTP/1.1. For wrapper languages, we can set the default authority for the entire channel via the channel arg: `grpc.default_authority`. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L248